# How do I create a domain scoped project on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I'm trying to create a domain scoped project so that my gcr.io registries look like `gcr.io/acme.com/project/image` rather than `gcr.io/project/image` like documented in https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#registry_name_format, but I'm unable to create a project with id `acme.com:project`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the colon with a slash. So your gcr.io address should be gcr.io/acme.com/project/image.

Note: domain scoped projects are deprecated and you haven't been able to make new domain scoped projects for years.

Comment: Docs: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting#domain-scoped_projects